# KeepAlive in Linux for Hamachi

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm currently having problems with my hamachi vpn connection.
The VPN connection keeps on disconnecting on the network. I saw a forum post that said to create a file in

```
~/.hamachi/config
```

with the content

```
KeepAlive 10
```

I don't want to corrupt the installed hamachi since im currently working on it remotely. And there's currently no one on site to check on it...

Anyway, my question is. Where exactly is the `~/.hamachi/config` directory?

The directories i found related to logmein-hamachi are

```
/run/logmein-hamachi

/opt/logmein-hamachi

/var/lib/logmein-hamachi
```

Where on this directory is the right place for me to create that file?

And what should be the file name? should it be just `config`?

or should I create the `.hamachi` folder (if so, on what directory) then create the `config` file there?

Also, I've never used KeepAlive. I guess its self-explanatory, it keeps the connection alive. But what is the 10 on the line KeepAlive 10? It keeps the connection alive when it cant ping for 10 seconds?

I'm new at this but I'm trying to learn as much as possible. Thank you!

Comment: `~` refers to your home directory. So `~/.hamachi` is unambiguously a location in your home directory: `/home/username/.hamachi`